# Teorema del invariante aplicado nested loops

Tags: lógica

tengo una duda con respecto a la lógica de Hoare que no se muy bien como aplicarla.
Supongamos que tenemos dos ciclos whiles con una condición B1 y B2; instrucciones S1 y S2

```
while B1:
   while B2:
      S2
   S1
```

Y luego tengo los invariantes I1 e I2
Ahora supongamos que pruebo el teorema del invariante para while 2 y la tripla es válida, entonces la precondición del while 2 implica el I2

Ahora una vez que se eso me quedan las siguientes triplas:

```
{Pc1}
While B1:
  {Pc2}
   While B2:
      S2
   {Qc2}
   S2
{Qc1}
```

Para la instrucción S2 puedo sacar la weakest precondition wp(S2,Qc1) y probar correctitud pero el while 2 no
Porque no existe una weakest precondition cerrada.
Si quiero por ejemplo probar la siguiente tripla de Hoare
`{I1 ^ B1} while B2 do..endwhile; S2 {I1}`
Tengo que probar que

```
I1 ^ B1 => wp(while B2 do .. endwhile; S2, I1)
```

Y lo que conozco es que

```
Pc2 => wp(while B2 do .. endwhile, Qc2)
```

como se probaria habiendo probado el ciclo interno?

Comment: hummm ... {Pc2} es la precondicion del ciclo interno, recuerda que el teorema de hoare  se aplica de manera iterativa.

Comment: entonces se aplica la invariante: {I1 ^ Pc2}